# Postgresql проверка курсора на пустоту

Tags: postgresql

подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше всего и удобнее проверить курсор на пустоту?

Суть вопроса, открываю курсор, записываю в него селект, далее надо проверить, если курсор пустой, то есть селект вернул 0 строк, то нужно в этот курсор или в новый записать другой селект и тогда вернуть его если он не пустой, иначе null возвращать. Я не могу понять как сделать (

Сделал такую белиберду, естественно не работает корректно, возвращает только одну строку.

Селект возвращаем много полей, около 10

```
BEGIN       
    OPEN cur1 FOR
        select * from test.return_exception s where s.id = id_d;
    FETCH FIRST FROM cur1 INTO check_size;
    IF check_size is not null THEN
        RETURN cur1;
    END IF;
    OPEN cur2 FOR
        select * from test.return_exception s where s.r_id = id_r;
    FETCH FIRST FROM cur2 INTO check_size;
    IF check_size is not null THEN
        RETURN cur2;    
    ELSE
        RETURN NULL;
END;
```

Comment: Проще сделать это одним запросом `select * from test.return_exception s where s.id = id_d
  or (not exists(select 1 from test.return_exception where id=id_d) and s.r_id = id_r)`

Comment: Но если очень хочется то видимо открывать курсор с возможностью SCROLL и использовать `move first` что бы открутить его к первой записи после первого fetch

Comment: @Mike спасибо большое в очередной раз, мне первого запроса в полне достаточно. Про not exist как-то в голову не пришло. В очередной раз выручили :)